# JAVA OpenGL 3D Transformation

Tags: java, opengl

I would like to apply two transformations on a SolidCube with Java OpenGL.
I'm using the methods "gl.glPushMatrix()" and "gl.glPopMatrix", but I need to use it twice, like is there a way to get the matrice resulting from the 1st transformation in order to use it straight into another "gl.glPushMatrix()"-"gl.glPopMatrix" bloc ?

an example :

```
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(1, 0, 1);
    glut.glutSolidCube(1);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

now i need to do another transformation on the cube from the its new position (from the point 1,0,1) with another Push/PopMatrix if possible.

```
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    (how to get the new position of the cube here ?)
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `glPushMatrix()` calls, which is the whole point of them.

In other words:

```
glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(1, 0, 0)
// draw something
glPopMatrix()

glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(1, 0, 0) // same as before
glTranslatef(0, 1, 0) // additional translation
// draw something else
glPopMatrix()
```

Would be the same as:

```
glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(1, 0, 0)
// draw something
glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(0, 1, 0) // now we only need the additional translation
// draw something else
glPopMatrix()
glPopMatrix()
```

So when you've translated, rotated, etc. Then if you want to save that state you call `glPushMatrix()`. Then you can apply additional translations, rotation, etc. Then when you want to get back to the state you call `glPopMatrix()`.

Comment: actually I do something like this : a first "glPushMatrix() - glPopMatrix()" in which i do a 1st transformation on a object, then another "glPushMatrix() - glPopMatrix()" to do a transformation on another.  What I want to do next is to apply another "glPushMatrix() - glPopMatrix()" to the object(s) resulting from the previous 2 "glPushMatrix() - glPopMatrix()".

Comment: I don't follow how that is different from what I mentioned? You can call `glTranslatef()` as many times as you want, between `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`

Comment: I'd like to put here all my code to explain you clearly what I mean but I fear that my teacher finds it on that site and say that I just did a copy/paste. but thanks for your answer, I just can't explain you exactly what I need to do. my bad.